# Including <returns> XML documentation block in Swagger Swashbuckle C#

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

If I create a method as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary here
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>THIS DOES NOT SHOW ANYWHERE</returns>
    /// <remarks>Remarks here</remarks>
    public async Task<string> MyMethod()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

And I have Swashbuckle.AspNetCore installed and setup, then the documentation is generated correctly, except the value in the `<returns>` block does not get generated into anything in the json:

```
"/api/v1.0/Exhibits/TestMethod1": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Blah"
        ],
        "summary": "Summary here",
        "description": "Remarks here",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

How can I persuade it to export this to a relevant field, or is this not possible?

Comment: [Adding Swagger to ASP.NET Core Web API using XML Documentation](https://exceptionnotfound.net/adding-swagger-to-asp-net-core-web-api-using-xml-documentation)

Comment: @stuartd the author of that article has the same issue "_If you're wondering where the returns XML node went, well, I'm not sure either. I'd appreciate if anyone could point out where it is in Swagger in the comments._"

Comment: Oh sorry missed that

Comment: I agree.  It would be nice to fall back on `<returns>` if there was no `<response>`, or to also show  `<returns>` in some way.

Answer (score 5):

The return description is different, depend on status code in each response.
so you need to specify what is description for each status code.

Swagger use one or more `<response code="xxx">` instead of single `<returns>`

your document should be look like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a specific product by unique id
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Awesomeness!</remarks>
/// <response code="200">return Product with spacific id</response>
/// <response code="400">Product Not found</response>
/// <response code="500">Oops! Can't Found your product right now due to internal error</response>
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Product), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public Product GetById(int id)
```

read [How to add method description in Swagger UI in WebAPI Application](https://newbedev.com/how-to-add-method-description-in-swagger-ui-in-webapi-application) for more

Comment: Is there no way to show `<returns>` at all?  E.g. to make it assume it is code 200, perhaps?